# Can states in a Plant UML state diagram be positioned relative to another state?

Tags: plantuml

I've made a plantuml state diagram which looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to position "MainActivity" state to the right of the "Idle" state, such that the arrows for [instruction] and [done] end up horizontal.

I know this is can be done for notes and text, but I haven't seen any syntax for the states themselves.

Is this possible in PlantUML?

For reference, this is my PlantUML script:

```
@startuml

skinparam state {
    StartColor PaleGreen
    EndColor Red
    BackgroundColor Gold
    BackgroundColor<<Junction>> GreenYellow  
    BorderColor Gray
    FontName Consolas
}

[*] -> Creating
Creating --> Idle : initialised
Idle : wait here for instructions
Idle --> MainActivity : [instruction]

state MainActivity {    
    [*] --> DoFirstThing    
    DoFirstThing --> FirstThingSuccess : [OK]
    DoFirstThing --> FirstThingFailed : [not OK]
    FirstThingSuccess --> SecondThing
    SecondThing --> SecondThingFailed
    SecondThing --> SecondThingSuccess  
    SecondThingSuccess --> WritingReport
    SecondThingFailed --> WritingReport
    FirstThingFailed --> WritingReport
    WritingReport --> [*]
}

MainActivity --> Idle : [done]

@enduml
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can define the direction of the arrows by inserting them in between the dashes of the arrow notation, such as "MainActivity -left-> Idle" (see section 7.5 in the PlantUML reference guide).

The following code :

```
plantuml
@startuml

skinparam state {
    StartColor PaleGreen
    EndColor Red
    BackgroundColor Gold
    BackgroundColor<<Junction>> GreenYellow  
    BorderColor Gray
    FontName Consolas
}

[*] -> Creating
Creating --> Idle : initialised
Idle : wait here for instructions
Idle -right-> MainActivity : [instruction]

state MainActivity {    
    [*] --> DoFirstThing    
    DoFirstThing --> FirstThingSuccess : [OK]
    DoFirstThing --> FirstThingFailed : [not OK]
    FirstThingSuccess --> SecondThing
    SecondThing --> SecondThingFailed
    SecondThing --> SecondThingSuccess  
    SecondThingSuccess --> WritingReport
    SecondThingFailed --> WritingReport
    FirstThingFailed --> WritingReport
    WritingReport --> [*]
}

MainActivity -left-> Idle : [done]

@enduml
```

gives you this diagramme :

[image]

(PS : You could do the same for the "Creating" state to make it look more consisten)

Comment: Why is the `[instruction]` arrow specified as `-left->`?  Shouldn't it be `-right->` (or just left as `->`)?

Comment: @mrtumnus, you are right. I did not notice this. It should indeed be `Idle -right-> MainActivity : [instruction]`. I just played around with the plantuml code and it seems to be related to the fact that there are two arrows between `Idle` and `MainActivity` with named directions. I played with several combinations of `left` and `right` on both arrows and the behavior seems very non-intuitive to me. Essentially, in my code above, the second arrow with `left` "won" over the `right` arrow...I will correct my code to avoid further confusion. But definitely sth to be careful about!

Comment: When you replace `Idle -right-> MainActivity : [instruction]` by just `Idle -> MainActivity : [instruction]`, the `Idle` state goes back to the top in a top-down layout style. It seems as if the same, seemingly erratic rendering behavior, overwrites the `left` in the line `MainActivity -left-> Idle : [done]`.

Comment: Yeah, the layout has seemed pretty unstable.  I think it has trouble with the composite states, because it seems to be laying out the "inner" states first, and the composite "parent" states get added in later.  Thanks for following up!